Adding line break inside a DIV when printing MySQL table contents
I'm a PHP newbie so please go easy.  Currently I have simple MySQL table which I'm attempting to list the contents of inside a DIV which is a CSS speech bubble.  The only problem I seem to be facing is it seems to be stacking the div on top of each other giving the illusion of only one table row being displayed.  If I echo a line break under the speech bubble DIV output echo it only adds one line, so I would need to put about 20 to have the speech bubbles separated. I've tried for a few days trying to put a line break inside the speech bubble DIV so each table row has it's own seperate speech bubble however have got nowhere. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. TIA
 <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT first_name, review, initial, approved FROM test";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $fielf4name = $row ['approved'];
        $field1name = $row["first_name"];
        $field2name = $row["initial"];
        $field3name = $row["review"];

        if ($row ['approved'] == "1")
        {
            echo '<div class="speech-bubble">', $field1name, ' ', $field2name, ' <br /><br />' , $field3name, ' </div> ' ;
        }
    
}

/*freeresultset*/
$result->free();
}

?> 

speech bubble CSS if needed
.speech-bubble {
   width: 70%; 
   height: auto; 
   background: #6d8c33;
   position: absolute;
   left:100px;
   -moz-border-radius: 10px; 
   -webkit-border-radius: 10px; 
   border-radius: 10px;
}
.speech-bubble:before {
   content:"";
   position: absolute;
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   border-top: 13px solid transparent;
   border-right: 26px solid #6d8c33;
   border-bottom: 13px solid transparent;
   margin: 13px 0 0 -25px;
}

I've tried using line breaks inside the DIV however keep getting syntax errors.

Try ignoring the database and PHP for now and focus solely on HTML and CSS

Thanks so much for the input.  I will go back and have a look at the CSS and HTML.  I seem to be going around in circles with this.
